# Solving for $x$ in the equation $xa^x = y$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations, transcendental-equations

I am trying to solve the equation

$$xa^x = y,$$

for $x$ where $x$ should be positive. 
The only thing known is $a < 1$. I tried taking logarithm of both side but it doesn't really lead anywhere.

Comment: [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=e^{ \alpha} $ and multiply by $\alpha$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha x e^{ \alpha x} =\alpha y .\\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now recall the Lambert $W$ function is defined by $we^w=z$ gives $w=W(z)$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
x&=& \frac{1}{\alpha}   (W(\alpha y)) \\
x&=& \frac{1}{\ln(a)}   (W(y \ln(a))). \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $\log a$ to get

$$x\log a\,e^{x\log a}=y\log a$$

and invert by

$$x\log a=W(y\log a).$$